navigateTo not working in plugin - nuxt 3
The problem in short: navigateTo works in defineNuxtRouteMiddleware but it does not work in defineNuxtPlugin. I do not want to run this code on every page only in or entering the site
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  // This data is variable depending on the user who is currently logged in, but for simplicity I will use a fixed object
  const user = {
    isTestUser : true
  };
  
  if(user.isTestUser) {
    return navigateTo("/test");
  }
});

An error also appears when returning navigateTo :
Argument of type '(nuxtApp: _NuxtApp) => false | void | RouteLocationRaw | Promise<false | void | NavigationFailure>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Plugin<Record<string, unknown>> | ObjectPlugin<Record<string, unknown>>'.
  Type '(nuxtApp: _NuxtApp) => false | void | RouteLocationRaw | Promise<false | void | NavigationFailure>' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<Record<string, unknown>>'.
    Type 'false | void | RouteLocationRaw | Promise<false | void | NavigationFailure>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void> | Promise<{ provide?: Record<string, unknown> | undefined; }> | { provide?: Record<string, unknown> | undefined; }'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void> | Promise<{ provide?: Record<string, unknown> | undefined; }> | { provide?: Record<string, unknown> | undefined; }'

in nuxt.config.ts :
ssr: false


Are you using a plugin or a middleware? I am confused.

I want to use plugin not middleware

Because I want to run this code once when entering the site

Why are you using defineNuxtPlugin then?

Why?? The defineNuxtPlugin works only once, while the defineNuxtRouteMiddleware works with every page. I want to use a Plugin to execute the code the first time it enters the site once. What do you mean by “Why use defineNuxtPlugin”?????

Explain more. If you have a suggestion or something specific, explain and clarify

Hm, a plugin is a plugin. The fact that it runs once is maybe true but the syntax of it is not the same. Maybe try that kind of syntax: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#parallel-plugins Also, I know in Nuxt2, we had store.$router.history, now accessible here on which one you could also have a conditional in a global middleware on the first render of the app. I hence was confused if you wanted to do the middleware way or the plugin, because both are IMO feasible.

For your use case, check nuxtApp. Don't you have a router instance on it that you could use to navigate?

export default defineNuxtPlugin({     name: 'my-plugin',     parallel: true,     async setup (nuxtApp) {     nuxtApp.$router.push("/test2");     }   })
not work nuxtApp.$router.push and i change syntax and not work  navigateTo()

What is inside nuxtApp? Maybe it's just router rather than $router?

There is a solution, but I do not expect it to be the best. There may be something better than that.. but for your information, I use ssr:fasle in nuxt.config.ts. The file also works on the client (test.client.ts).
Although the page will reload this way..
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  const route = useRoute();
  const user = {
    isTestUser: true,
  };

  // For example, you can verify in other ways, but for simplicity, for example: route.path !== '/test'
  if (user.isTestUser && route.path !== '/test' ) {  
   window.location.href = "/test"; // <===
  }
});

!!important!!
Make sure that the current page or the current route is not equal to the page you want, because if it is on the landing page or the intended route, you do not need to redirect.

If your are using { SSR: false } option in your nuxt.config.ts. You might want to consider using a global middleware and the "isHydrating" flag like so:
// middleware/01.test.global.js

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware( async (to, from) => {
  if (!useNuxtApp().isHydrating) return
  
  const toPath = '/'

  if (to.path === toPath) return

  const user = {
    isTestUser : true
  };
  
  if(user.isTestUser) {
    return navigateTo(toPath);
  }
})

The "isHydrating" will to true only on first load and false on page navigation.
More info here: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#when-middleware-runs
